# Simplyfing functions to plot multiple lines in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, simplify

I read a case with the same title in stackoverflow, but it did not solve my questions.
I have a data frame like this:

```
ID T1 T2 T3 T4....T10
1  40 50 50 70....40
2  30 60 29 50....NA
3  59 80 NA NA....NA
4  80 90 90 NA....NA
```

I want to have just one graph putting T1, T2, T3...T10 on the x-axis, and the scores in T1, T2...T10 on the y-axis. Each id forms a single line with the changing of the scores. I used **add=TRUE** for each one, but it is still cumbersome because I have more than 300 IDs. How can I do it quickly in plot or even ggplot?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `matplot`. However, 300 lines in one plot are not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:5,t1=1:5,t2=2:6,t3=3:7)
d[3,4]=NA
d
plot(1:(length(d)-1),ylim=range(d,na.rm=TRUE),type="n",xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) points(unlist(d[i,])[-1],col=i,type="o")
axis(1,at=1:(length(d)-1),labels=names(d)[-1])
```

Comment: Ah, forgot about `matplot(d[,-1])`. So many useful things built into R (if maybe not so useful in this case as @Roland points out).

Comment: Thanks, DaveTurek. But there are NAs at different locations for different IDs. What I am sure is that once there is an NA in one row, the rest columns in that row will be all NAs.

Comment: @William Liu it looks to me like both my code and `matplot` should handle those cases. (Though it should be `matplot(t(d[,-1]),...)`.)  Am I missing something?